# Opencv import highgui in android studio is showing error.Cannot resolve(I added the library still the error remain)

Tags: android, opencv, image-segmentation

I have the following code which is for image segmentation using grabcut opencv. I am using opencv for the first time. I added the opencv library. While others worked perfectly highgui is still showing cannot resolve symbol.Do i need to add something else.
(**If you can help me with the code too, will be an additional help**)
Here is the code:
**Edit : I have posted the updated code:**

```
       package com.example.android.seg;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;


import java.io.IOException;

import org.opencv.android.OpenCVLoader;
import org.opencv.android.Utils;
import org.opencv.core.Core;
import org.opencv.core.CvType;
import org.opencv.core.Mat;
import org.opencv.core.Point;
import org.opencv.core.Rect;
import org.opencv.core.Scalar;
import org.opencv.imgproc.Imgproc;
import org.opencv.core.*;
import org.opencv.imgcodecs.Imgcodecs; // imread, imwrite, etc
   // VideoCapture

import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnTouchListener;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;


public class seg extends Activity implements OnTouchListener {
    static{
        if (!OpenCVLoader.initDebug()) {
            Log.i("TEST", "Cannot connect to OpenCV Manager");
            // Handle initialization error
        }
        else {
            Log.i("TEST", "Connected to OpenCV Manager");
        }
    }
    ImageView imageView;
    Bitmap bitmap;
    Canvas canvas;
    Scalar color = new Scalar(255, 0, 0, 255);
    Point tl, br;
    int counter;
    Bitmap bitmapResult, bitmapBackground;
    Mat dst = new Mat();
    //"sdcard/DCIM/wall.jpg"
    final String pathToImage  = "wall.jpg";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_seg);
        imageView = (ImageView) this.findViewById(R.id.imageView);

        bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(pathToImage);
        Toast msg = Toast.makeText(seg.this, "Press top left and bottom right of the      foreground image", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);

        msg.setGravity(Gravity.TOP|Gravity.LEFT, 0, 0);

        msg.show();
        bitmapResult = bitmap.copy(bitmap.getConfig(), true);
        canvas = new Canvas(bitmapResult);

        imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmapResult);
        imageView.setOnTouchListener(this);

        tl = new Point();
        br = new Point();
        counter = 0;
    }

    //@Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

        if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
            if (counter == 0) {
                tl.x = event.getX();
                tl.y = event.getY();
                counter++;
            } else if (counter == 1) {
                br.x = event.getX();
                br.y = event.getY();
                counter++;

                Mat img = new Mat();
                //val mat = Imgcodecs.imread(pathToImage)
                img = Imgcodecs.imread(pathToImage);
                Mat background = new Mat();
                try {
                    background = Utils.loadResource(getApplicationContext(),
                            R.drawable.wall );
                } catch (IOException e) {

                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                backgroundSubtracting(img, background);
                Imgcodecs.imwrite("wall.jpg", dst);
                //Highgui.imwrite("/mnt/sdcard/GRABCUT/rect.png", dst);
                Bitmap jpg = BitmapFactory
                        .decodeFile("wall.jpg");

                imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_INSIDE);
                imageView.setAdjustViewBounds(true);
                imageView.setPadding(2, 2, 2, 2);
                imageView.setImageBitmap(jpg);
                imageView.invalidate();
            }
        }

        return true;
    }

    private void backgroundSubtracting(Mat img, Mat background) {

        Mat firstMask = new Mat();
        Mat bgModel = new Mat();
        Mat fgModel = new Mat();
        Mat mask;
        Mat source = new Mat(1, 1, CvType.CV_8U, new Scalar(3.0));
        dst = new Mat();
        Rect rect = new Rect(tl, br);

        Imgproc.grabCut(img, firstMask, rect, bgModel, fgModel, 1, 0 /* GC_INIT_WITH_RECT */);
        Core.compare(firstMask, source/* GC_PR_FGD */, firstMask, Core.CMP_EQ);

        Mat foreground = new Mat(img.size(), CvType.CV_8UC3, new Scalar(255,
                255, 255));
        img.copyTo(foreground, firstMask);
        Imgproc.rectangle(img, tl, br, color);
        //Core.rectangle(img, tl, br, color);

        Mat tmp = new Mat();
        Imgproc.resize(background, tmp, img.size());
        background = tmp;
        mask = new Mat(foreground.size(), CvType.CV_8UC1, new Scalar(255, 255, 255));

        Imgproc.cvtColor(foreground, mask, 6/* COLOR_BGR2GRAY */);
        Imgproc.threshold(mask, mask, 254, 255, 1 /* THRESH_BINARY_INV */);

        Mat vals = new Mat(1, 1, CvType.CV_8UC3, new Scalar(0.0));
        background.copyTo(dst);

        background.setTo(vals, mask);
        Core.add(background, foreground, dst, mask);

        firstMask.release();
        source.release();
        bgModel.release();
        fgModel.release();
        vals.release();
    }

}
```

**here is my logcat:**

```
  05-20 09:48:51.830  24423-24423/com.example.android.seg D/dalvikvm﹕ Late-enabling CheckJNI
05-20 09:48:51.832  24423-24429/com.example.android.seg D/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=2: interp stack at 0x40000000
05-20 09:48:51.840  24423-24431/com.example.android.seg D/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=3: interp stack at 0x40008000
05-20 09:48:51.840  24423-24423/com.example.android.seg D/jdwp﹕ prepping for JDWP over ADB
05-20 09:48:51.840  24423-24423/com.example.android.seg D/jdwp﹕ ADB transport startup
05-20 09:48:51.841  24423-24432/com.example.android.seg D/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=4: interp stack at 0x49247000
05-20 09:48:51.841  24423-24432/com.example.android.seg D/jdwp﹕ JDWP: thread running
05-20 09:48:51.841  24423-24432/com.example.android.seg D/jdwp﹕ acceptConnection
05-20 09:48:51.842  24423-24432/com.example.android.seg D/jdwp﹕ trying to receive file descriptor from ADB
05-20 09:48:51.842  24423-24433/com.example.android.seg D/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=5: interp stack at 0x4bd75000
05-20 09:48:51.851  24423-24432/com.example.android.seg D/jdwp﹕ received file descriptor 40 from ADB
05-20 09:48:51.853  24423-24435/com.example.android.seg D/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=6: interp stack at 0x4bd7d000
05-20 09:48:51.854  24423-24435/com.example.android.seg D/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=6: calling run()
05-20 09:48:51.855  24423-24432/com.example.android.seg D/jdwp﹕ processIncoming
05-20 09:48:51.855  24423-24432/com.example.android.seg D/jdwp﹕ processIncoming
05-20 09:48:51.855  24423-24432/com.example.android.seg D/jdwp﹕ handlePacket : cmd=0x1, cmdSet=0xC7, len=0x13, id=0x40000044, flags=0x0, dataLen=0x8
05-20 09:48:51.856  24423-24432/com.example.android.seg D/jdwp﹕ REQ: DDM.Chunk (cmd=199/1 dataLen=8 id=0x40000044)
05-20 09:48:51.857  24423-24432/com.example.android.seg D/jdwp﹕ reply: dataLen=9 err=NONE(0)
05-20 09:48:51.857  24423-24432/com.example.android.seg D/jdwp﹕ processIncoming
05-20 09:48:51.857  24423-24432/com.example.android.seg D/jdwp﹕ handlePacket : cmd=0x1, cmdSet=0xC7, len=0x17, id=0x40000045, flags=0x0, dataLen=0xC
05-20 09:48:51.857  24423-24432/com.example.android.seg D/jdwp﹕ REQ: DDM.Chunk (cmd=199/1 dataLen=12 id=0x40000045)
05-20 09:48:51.859  24423-24432/com.example.android.seg D/jdwp﹕ reply: dataLen=50 err=NONE(0)
05-20 09:48:51.860  24423-24432/com.example.android.seg D/jdwp﹕ processIncoming
05-20 09:48:51.860  24423-24432/com.example.android.seg D/jdwp﹕ handlePacket : cmd=0x1, cmdSet=0xC7, len=0x13, id=0x40000046, flags=0x0, dataLen=0x8
05-20 09:48:51.860  24423-24432/com.example.android.seg D/jdwp﹕ REQ: DDM.Chunk (cmd=199/1 dataLen=8 id=0x40000046)
05-20 09:48:51.862  24423-24432/com.example.android.seg D/jdwp﹕ reply: dataLen=216 err=NONE(0)
05-20 09:48:51.862  24423-24432/com.example.android.seg D/jdwp﹕ processIncoming
05-20 09:48:51.862  24423-24432/com.example.android.seg D/jdwp﹕ handlePacket : cmd=0x1, cmdSet=0xC7, len=0x13, id=0x40000047, flags=0x0, dataLen=0x8
05-20 09:48:51.863  24423-24432/com.example.android.seg D/jdwp﹕ REQ: DDM.Chunk (cmd=199/1 dataLen=8 id=0x40000047)
05-20 09:48:51.863  24423-24432/com.example.android.seg D/jdwp﹕ reply: dataLen=9 err=NONE(0)
05-20 09:48:51.863  24423-24432/com.example.android.seg D/jdwp﹕ processIncoming
05-20 09:48:51.863  24423-24432/com.example.android.seg D/jdwp﹕ handlePacket : cmd=0x1, cmdSet=0xC7, len=0x14, id=0x40000048, flags=0x0, dataLen=0x9
05-20 09:48:51.863  24423-24432/com.example.android.seg D/jdwp﹕ REQ: DDM.Chunk (cmd=199/1 dataLen=9 id=0x40000048)
05-20 09:48:51.863  24423-24432/com.example.android.seg D/jdwp﹕ reply: dataLen=0 err=NONE(0)
05-20 09:48:51.863  24423-24436/com.example.android.seg D/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=7: interp stack at 0x4bd85000
05-20 09:48:51.864  24423-24436/com.example.android.seg D/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=7: calling run()
05-20 09:48:51.872  24423-24437/com.example.android.seg D/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=8: interp stack at 0x4bd8d000
05-20 09:48:51.873  24423-24437/com.example.android.seg D/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=8: calling run()
05-20 09:48:52.050  24423-24439/com.example.android.seg D/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=9: interp stack at 0x4bd95000
05-20 09:48:52.052  24423-24440/com.example.android.seg D/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=10: interp stack at 0x4bd9d000
05-20 09:48:52.064  24423-24423/com.example.android.seg D/jdwp﹕ sendBufferedRequest : len=0x39
05-20 09:48:52.918  24423-24423/com.example.android.seg D/jdwp﹕ sendBufferedRequest : len=0x45
05-20 09:48:53.289  24423-24423/com.example.android.seg D/ActivityThread﹕ BIND_APPLICATION handled : 0 / AppBindData{appInfo=ApplicationInfo{41615870 com.example.android.seg}}
05-20 09:48:53.296  24423-24423/com.example.android.seg D/OpenCV/StaticHelper﹕ Trying to get library list
05-20 09:48:53.296  24423-24423/com.example.android.seg D/dalvikvm﹕ Trying to load lib /mnt/asec/com.example.android.seg-2/lib/libopencv_info.so 0x41618e00
05-20 09:48:53.297  24423-24423/com.example.android.seg A/libc﹕ Fatal signal 7 (SIGBUS) at 0x4bf6d9b8 (code=2)
```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

**In opencv3.0, there is no more highgui module in java.**

the functionality was split up into new `videoio` and `imgcodecs` (that's where you will find imread) modules.

```
import org.opencv.core.*;
import org.opencv.imgcodecs; // imread, imwrite, etc
import org.opencv.videoio;   // VideoCapture
```

**EDIT:** Change `img=Highgui.imread(pathtoimage);` to `img = Imgcodecs.imread(pathtoimage);`

and `Core.rectangle(img, tl, br, color);` to `Imgproc.rectangle(img, t1, br, color);`

I will also suggest go through [OpenCV 3.0 modules](http://docs.opencv.org/master/) to resolve these errors.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/78309/discussion-on-answer-by-exception-opencv-import-highgui-in-android-studio-is-sho).

Comment: Exception or can someone help me in this matter, I really need to do this. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61876457/image-segmentation-using-segment-seeds-watershed-in-android

Answer (score 3):

Depending on the file structure it may instead be:

```
import org.opencv.imgcodecs.Imgcodecs;
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no Highgui module in OpenCV 3.0+ instead you can use the same Imgcodecs module

The old one

```
Highgui.imread(fileName, Highgui.CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE)
Highgui.imread(fileName)
```

The New one

```
Imgcodecs.imread(fileName, Imgcodecs.CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE)
Imgcodecs.imread(fileName)
```